# free $G$-set with a free generating set

Tags: abstract-algebra

Does a "free $G$-set $X$ with free generating set $B$" mean that for any $x\in X$,
there exist unique $g_1,\cdots,g_n\in G$ and $b_1,\cdots, b_n\in B$ such that
$x=g_1b_1+\cdots +g_nb_n$? I want to mimic the definition of basis for a free module/vector field, but the formal sum here doesn't quite seem to make sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, free $G$-set is a disjoint union of orbits which are isomorphic to $G$ (of course, isomorphic as $G$-sets).

Comment: so can I say that, "a G-set $X$ is free with generating set $B$ iff for any $x\in X$, there exist unique $g\in G, b\in B$ such that $gb=x$"?

Comment: Yes, certainly.

Comment: You are welcom!